# How to SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "staging"

Tags: zend-framework, environment-variables

I have a staging server setup something like this:
http://staging.mysite.com

the method below works just fine for my development environment.

In the .htaccess file, i included:
    `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "staging"`

Yet Zend still thinks the environment is production.

        `<title>My Site :: <?= APPLICATION_ENV; ?></title>`

yields: 
My Site :: production 
in the title bar of the browser.

I have searched multiple threads and tried using the 
SetEnvIf directive as well with no luck.

Please help!

Comment: http://es.php.net/getenv

Comment: ok, since mediatemple constrains us, i fixed it like so:
    // Define application environment
    if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV')){
 switch ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]){
  case "staging.mysite.com": define('APPLICATION_ENV','staging'); break;
  case "mysite.dev": define('APPLICATION_ENV','development'); break;
  default : define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
 }
}

Answer (score 3):

`SetEnv` simply sets the Apache environment variable, you can access this with PHP in `$_SERVER` or using PHP's getenv() function as ZiTAL posted above. You probably want something like this somewhere early in your app (e.g. index.php):

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

This populates the constant with the environment variable value unless it is already defined, falling back to the value of 'production' if the env var isn't populated.

Comment: removing the quotes doesn't work.i think the problem is mediaTemple doesn't have mod_setenv enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Under my local server running php on fcgi, the following `.htaccess` directive

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

results in the following `$_SERVER` variable

```
...
[REDIRECT_APPLICATION_ENV] => development
...
```

Comment: Do you understand why that happens? I'm having the same thing on a test server of mine...

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the double quote:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV staging
```

and check the return of `getenv` in PHP:

```
echo getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');
```